# Calcute mean for same time on different dates

Tags: r, datetime

I have data that shows a numeric amount of something measured at a few seconds after every minute of every day over a period of several days. Here is an example for two minutes on three days:

```
dat <- read.table(textConnection('
date_and_time amount
"2020-05-01 13:23:02" 8
"2020-05-01 13:24:06" 26
"2020-05-02 13:23:01" 5
"2020-05-02 13:24:01" 30
"2020-05-03 13:23:03" 6
"2020-05-03 13:24:02" 27
'), header = TRUE, colClasses=c("POSIXct", "numeric"))
```

For that data, I want to calculate the mean amount for each minute over all days. For the above sample data, the result would look like this:

```
time_of_day mean_amount
13:23:00 6.333333
13:24:00 27.66667
```

To get that result, I have converted the datetime objects to character strings, stripped the dates and the seconds from the strings, converted the strings to a factor, and calculated the means for each factor.

**Is there a way to achieve that result with the datetime objects?** That is, is there a function to calculate means over the same time of different dates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by datetime you mean POSIXct then that class cannot represent times without a date; however, the chron times class can.

The following converts the date/time to a chron object, `ch`, and then converts that to a times object, `time_of_day`, and truncate that to the minute. Finally we aggregate `amount` by that.

```
library(chron)

ch <- as.chron(format(dat$date_and_time))
time_of_day <- trunc(ch - dates(ch), "min")
ag <- aggregate(amount ~ time_of_day, dat, mean)
```

giving:

```
> ag
  time_of_day    amount
1    13:23:00  6.333333
2    13:24:00 27.666667

> str(ag)
'data.frame':   2 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ time_of_day: 'times' num  13:23:00 13:24:00
  ..- attr(*, "format")= chr "h:m:s"
 $ amount     : num  6.33 27.67
```

Answer (score 0):

in Base-R

```
sapply(split(dat$amount,format(dat$date_and_time, format='%H:%M')), mean)

    13:23     13:24 
 6.333333 27.666667
```

I used the `format` function to strip the days and seconds. You could use other ways of calculating the mean from that as well.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is no. Objects of class `POSIXct` must have a date.

Here's an approach with `lubridate` and `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
dat %>%
  mutate(hour = hour(date_and_time),
         minute = minute(date_and_time)) %>%
  group_by(hour,minute) %>%
  dplyr::summarise(mean_amount = mean(amount))
#   hour minute mean_amount
#  <int>  <int>       <dbl>
#1    13     23        6.33
#2    13     24       27.7
```

Comment: See my answer regarding using `POSIXct` objects without the date.

Answer (score 0):

additional solution

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(hms)

dat %>% 
  mutate(time = floor_date(x = date_and_time, unit = "min") %>% hms::as_hms()) %>% 
  group_by(time) %>% 
  summarise(mean_amount = mean(amount))
```